# DNS with BIND9 on Debian

Tags: dns, debian, named, bind9

I am trying to create my own dns using Bind9 and Debian 11
One Virtual Machine in Google Computing Engine has these configuration

Server 1 Google Cloud IP 35.206.115.212
The file /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
35.206.115.212 ns1.itinfrastructuretest.info ns1
10.128.0.2 instance-1.us-central1-a.c.dns-1902.internal instance-1  # Added by Google
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal  # Added by Google
```

The file /etc/hostname

```
ns1
```

The File /etc/bind/zones/db.35.206.115

```
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     itinfrastructuretest.info. root.itinfrastructuretest.info. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
        IN      NS      ns1.itinfrastructuretest.info.
        IN      NS      ns2.itinfrastructuretest.info.


1       IN      PTR     ns1.itinfrastructuretest.info.
2       IN      PTR     ns2.itinfrastructuretest.info.
3       IN      PTR     www.itinfrastructuretest.info.
```

The File /etc/bind/zones/db.itinfrastructuretest.info

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.itinfrastructuretest.info. root.itinfrastructuretest.info. (
                              5         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;

; Name servers
itinfrastructuretest.info.    IN      NS      ns1.itinfrastructuretest.info.
itinfrastructuretest.info.    IN      NS      ns2.itinfrastructuretest.info.

; A records for name servers
ns1             IN      A       35.206.115.212
ns2             IN      A       15.236.156.144

; Other A records
@               IN      A       15.236.147.109
www             IN      A       15.236.147.109
                IN      TXT     google-site-verification=EdC5AxyrHZ-HnRwyCgjckdIiFgFDzLniOyS2Tm6MwAk
; Mail server MX record
```

The File /etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "itinfrastructuretest.info" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/zones/db.itinfrastructuretest.info";
 allow-transfer { 15.236.156.144; };
};

zone "115.206.35.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        notify no;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.35.206.115";
};
```

The File /etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        dnssec-validation auto;

        listen-on-v6 { any; };

recursion no;
allow-transfer { none; };
auth-nxdomain no;
};
```

Server 2 Amazon Cloud IP 15.236.156.144
The Second Server on AWS
The /etc/hosts

```
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
#     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
#
127.0.1.1 ip-172-31-45-28.eu-west-3.compute.internal ip-172-31-45-28 ns2 ns2
127.0.0.1 localhost
15.236.156.144 ns2.itinfrastructuretest.info ns2
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

The file /etc/hostname

```
ns2
```

The File /etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "itinfrastructuretest.info"{
  type slave;
  file "db.itinfrastructuretest.info";
  masters { 35.206.115.212;};
};

zone "156.236.15.in-addr.arpa" {
        type slave;
        file "db.15.236.156";
        masters {35.206.115.212 ;};
};
```

The File /etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

 dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        allow-transfer { none; };
        recursion no;

};
```

I was following these tutorials

[How To Configure Bind as an Authoritative-Only DNS Server on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-an-authoritative-only-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

and 
[BIND9ServerHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto)

The uploaded image shows that nothing was transferred from the master dns to the slave dns.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h17uG.png)

When I run dig command in the master dns server I got this

```
 dig 35.206.115.212 115.206.35.in-addr.arpa. AXFR

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1-Debian <<>> 35.206.115.212 115.206.35.in-addr.arpa. AXFR
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 39639
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;35.206.115.212.                        IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       86385   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2020051700 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 169.254.169.254#53(169.254.169.254)
;; WHEN: Sun May 17 09:38:42 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 118

; Transfer failed.
```

Comment: Your question is off topic here as not related to programming, but 1) you shouldn't deal with the reverse tree, at least not before understanding the DNS well and making sure you have the delegation there (in most cases your ISP won't delegate the reverse tree to you), 2) your dig query makes no sense with two data requested and 3) you should always use the `@` parameter with dig to specify which nameserver you query

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried @ before dig command. However, there is something I am not sure about. Can I build my own DNS, SMTP, CA in cloud by cloud providers like AMAZON, GOOGLE, and MICROSOFT? or I have to use the services for these protocols that are provided by the cloud providers? Amazon Route 53, Amazon SES, and AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) Private Certificate Authority (CA)